# What is the best way to login to the Azure Devops CLI from a Release Pipeline?

Tags: oauth, azure-devops, command-line-interface

I am using the Azure Devops CLI on one of my pipelines. In order to use the CLI I need first login (authenticate). Unlike using the REST API, I can't use the OAuth token that is available to me.

So here's my understanding of my options:

1. I can do an "az login" using a PAT that I map to this environment variable:

AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT

**THIS IS THE WAY I'm doing it now.**

2. Apparently you can use a Service Principal. I like this the most because I should theoretically be able to have this principal apply to everyone on my team. Is that correct?
3. Use "az login" with a user/password. This is least desirable way to doing it because it involves passing around credentials. Too messy.
4. Although my pipeline has the OAuth token expost (System.AccessToken), it cannot be use by the CLI. For example is I try to assign the value of the OAuth token to the AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT it fails (AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT=$System.AccessToken).

**Questions:**

1. Is it possible to use the OAuth token to log in to the CLI?
2. Is the Service Principal the best way to go?

Additional Info:

I do not have subscriptions only a tenant-id, we're not creating any Azure resources, we're an AWS shop that happens to be using ADO only for CICD.

Comment: Is it possible for you to create a service connection and use it in your Azure CLI Task? I see you have 2 possibilities: Use a generic service connection or an azure classic one.

Comment: I actually do have a service connection set up, but the task is still asking me to login using "az login".  Do you have experience with this?

Comment: Azure CLI task is executing "az.cmd" login --service-principal -u *** -p *** --tenant ***" anyway. You should create a special Build User in your AD with appropriate rights. If this does not help, can you post the output from azure cli task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `az devops login` instead of `az login`

From your pipeline use:

```
- script: echo $(AccessToken) | az devops login
  env:
    AccessToken: $(System.AccessToken)
```

Few interesting notes:

- Secrets (like System.AccessToken) are available to scripts unless you pass them in explicitly as environment variables
- the System.AccessToken variable is the default access token of the build agent
- there is a project-specific build agent and a project-collection build agent. The one you use is actually controlled by the 'limit access to current project scope' flag in the Pipeline settings for the project.
- you may need to elevate permissions for the build agent if you're trying to manipulate objects. For example, you could grant the *Create Tag* permission on a repository if you wanted the build agent to update the repository.
- you can also create your own PAT token with permissions that you specify.